# Problem with Postgresql and Spring Boot 3 Error "Cannot resolve method 'type'"

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am updating my spring boot 2.7 JPA project to Spring boot 3.
I saved avatars in a postgresql database.

excerpt from my pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

My Database column create:

```
    id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL

old Version @Entity

    @Lob
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ImageType")
    @Column(length = 20971520)
    private byte[] avatar;
```

Now I get the following error
"Cannot resolve method 'type'"

I've tried too:

```
@Lob
@Column(length = 20971520)
private byte[] avatar;
```

How do I solve the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my code from:

```
@Lob
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.StringType")
private String note;
```

to:

```
@Lob
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.LONGVARCHAR)
private String note;
```

It may not work in your case but it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, the example did not help unfortunately. I can't find a suitable TYPE for byte[]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this problem:

OLD Version

```
@Lob
//20 MB
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.ImageType")
@Column(length = 20971520)
private byte[] avatar;
```

NEW Version

```
@Lob
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.LONGVARBINARY)
@Column(length = 20971520)
private byte[] avatar;
```